# Двустороннее взаимодействие между JavaScript и Java

Tags: javascript, java

Реальна ли такая тема: взаимодействие между JavaScript и работающим приложением, написанном на Java

Например, в браузере на странице кликнули по какому-нибудь элементу, например, кнопке. У кнопки (элемента) есть атрибут `onClick="..."`. Вызывается обработчик клика и из того обработчика вызывается функция в работающем Java приложении. В ту функцию, например, передается `Id` элемента (кнопки) по которому (-рой) был клик.

Как такое можно реализовать, не используя сокеты, апплеты, JSP и прочее?

Нагуглил про технологию "LiveConnect", но так и не понял - она работает только с апплетами или ей по-барабану. Всюду пример - апплеты. Время идет, а вопрос никак не решается...

Также нужен вызов функций Java-Script со стороны Java!

---

**update**: уточнения из комментариев:

- Java-приложение работает на клиенте (той же машине, что и браузер). Можно считать, что оно всегда запущено.
- Веб-страничка, JS на которой должен взаимодействовать с локальным приложением - является интерфейсом (WebUI) локальной программы.
- Браузер - старенький InternetExplorer 6. Ось - Винда. Настройки браузера менять можно.

Comment: А где работает "приложение на Java" - на сервере или на клиенте? Если на клиенте, то как оно туда попадает - речь о том, что пользователь заходит на сайт, должно запускаться приложение на Java или оно независимо устанавливается на машину пользователя и вопрос, как с уже установленным приложением взаимодействовать из JS браузера? Вы можете менять и JS и Java-код? Чем вас не устраивают сокеты?

Comment: Все работает на клиенте и все запущенно постоянно и работает всегда. Сокеты устроили бы, но начальство против них.

Comment: Да, вопрос более правильный такой - взаимодействие с запущеныпм Java-приложением из браузера. Причем - взаимодействие - двустороннее.

Comment: Про "начальство против" - как-то несерьезно, должны быть объективные причины быть против, вам же не запрещают букву "A" использовать в программах... Кроме того, для нормального ответа нужно еще больше контекста: какие браузеры/ОС вы поддерживаете, для каких сайтов эта фича должна работать - это просто web ui локальной программы или какой-то публичный сайт, - можете ли ставить расширения на браузеры, менять их настройки...

Comment: Браузер  - старенький InternetExplorer 6. Ось - Винда. Будет не сайт, а простая HTML страница - так сказать - пользовательский интерфейс или WebUI локальной программы. Настройки браузера менять можно

Comment: Ответил до того, как заметил уточнение. В общем я по прежнему за вариант (2) из своего ответа, так вам меньше всего времени нужно будет тратить на разбирательство с особенностями настроек устаревшего браузера. Существующего решения, которое прозрачно обеспечивает взаимодействие JS в браузере со сторонней уже запущенной Java-программой, мне не известно.

Comment: Простите за археологию, но мне все же интересно, а веб страничка где хостится?

Comment: Достаточно распространенная практика. Программа поднимает обычный локальный HTTP сервер (я уверен, что на Java есть десятки библиотек для этого) на котором хостит свой Web UI. Пользователь открывает в браузере `http://localhost:<порт сервера>` и управляет программой. Вызовы JS->Java обычный AJAХ. Для вызовов в обратную сторону есть разные решения (http://stackoverflow.com/a/12855533/409863). Или я неправильно понял требования?

Answer (score 1):

По очевидным причинам, браузеры не позволяют произвольным web-сайтам взаимодействовать с произвольными локальными приложениями - это была бы масштабная дырка в безопасности.

Поэтому вам надо:

- либо 1) модифицировать браузер так, чтобы конкретно вашей веб-страничке можно было больше, чем остальным (расширения/настройки)
- либо 2) сделать вашу программу доступной через интерфейсы, к которым разрешено обращаться веб-страничкам.

Конкретно [LiveConnect](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/liveconnect-docs-349790.html#INTRODUCTION) - это функция, которую сейчас реализует Oracle Java Plugin. Да, она только для аплетов, и не меняя настройки безопасности аплеты не смогут коммуницировать с локальной программой. Помимо всего прочего, производители браузеров отрицательно настроены по отношению к плагинам, поэтому по моему скромному мнению эта технология не имеет будущего и вам не стоит ее изучать и строить на ней продукты без крайней необходимости.

Вариант (1) "модифицировать браузер" требует повторения для разных браузеров (если вам нужно их поддерживать) и тоже куча копания.

Вариант (2) выглядит наиболее красивым. В идеале вы саму веб-страничку располагаете на http://localhost/ , с нее взаимодействуете с локальным приложением посредством стандартных веб-технологий (XMLHttpRequest в сторону клиент->сервер, [Comet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) в обратную - или, если у вас только современные браузеры, то web-sockets).

Comment: Спасибо!, как вариант, буду пробовать!

Comment: @SeaMan75: почему я про сокеты уточнял - все эти XMLHttpRequest и пр. будут использовать внутри именно их.

Comment: @SeaMan75 если ориентироваться на такое старьё как ie6, но воспользоваться новыми направлениями, можно сделать и на websocket, сделав эмуляцию ws в браузере на флэш(если интересно могу дать ссылку)

Comment: А если браузер старый (ie6) и в системе нет никакого WebServera, то, получается, запросами уже никак?

Comment: @SeaMan75 скорее всего - никак

Comment: да, было бы супер по поводу эмуляции ws на старом браузере! ссылка очень нужна!

Comment: @SeaMan75 вы не поняли. Вы добавляете в ваше Java-приложение, с которым хотели коммуницировать, веб-сервер - т.е. код, который слушает запросы от браузера и может на них реагировать: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3732328/1026

Comment: и еще, говорят, что JavaScript умеет обращаться к классам Java программы. Так это или не так - не знаю. Через LiveConnect - умеет к апплету, а к обычному приложению - никак? Скорее всего - никак, так как JavaScript не знает, что происходит за пределами браузера...

Comment: @SeaMan75 http://java-websocket.org/

Comment: спасибо!, сейчас буду разбираться!

Comment: @SeaMan75 в приложении можно сделать слушатель запросов. а вот как он будет реагировать на запущенный локальный html в котором идет подключение ws://localhost ....  По ws можно дергать методы в java, но это не так просто, можно и функции в js запускать, и это тоже своя специфика. если что обращайся это всё сделано :).

Comment: "можно и функции в js запускать, ", то есть из JS можно запускать функции запущенного Java-приложения?

Comment: @SeaMan75 ws (https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets) служит для передачи данных, в данных может находится и имя метода/функции, которыми будет обработаны данные.

Comment: ясно ок пасиб! все сводится к ws.

Comment: Вопрос решился использованием JSObject, но решил задачу не я, поэтому не могу сказать, как там и что...

Comment: Всем спасибо за участие!

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите на NW.js. Это смесь из Node.js и V8 (Chromium). На npm есть пакеты позволяющие выполнять Java код прямо в клиентском JavaScript. Из этого-же клиентского кода Вы можете вызывать node.js. NW.js позволяет собирать приложения для Windows, Unix и Mac систем.